# Unable to use data from chlid component to parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made this react app in which there's a Parent component as `App.js` and it has three child components.The first child component has some states which are being changed by the other two child components present in parent component.

So first I'm passing the states in parent component and then passing them into other two child components as props. Here's the piece of my code.

Here's my `App.js`

```
function App() {
  var firstvalueoftextarea,
    setfirstvalueoftextarea,
    secondvalueoftextarea,
    setsecondvalueoftextarea;

  var PanelOfResult = function(
    firstvalueoftextarea,
    setfirstvalueoftextarea,
    secondvalueoftextarea,
    setsecondvalueoftextarea
  ) {
    firstvalueoftextarea = firstvalueoftextarea;
    setfirstvalueoftextarea = setfirstvalueoftextarea;
    secondvalueoftextarea = secondvalueoftextarea;
    setsecondvalueoftextarea = setsecondvalueoftextarea;
  };

  return (
    console.log("Rendering of component"),
    (
      <div className="App">
        <ResultPanel PanelOfResult={PanelOfResult} />

        <SecondChildComponent
          valueoftextarea={firstvalueoftextarea}
          setvalueoftextarea={setfirstvalueoftextarea}
        />
        <ThirdChildComponent
          className="Symbols"
          firstvalueoftextarea={firstvalueoftextarea}
          setfirstvalueoftextarea={setfirstvalueoftextarea}
          secondvalueoftextarea={secondvalueoftextarea}
          setsecondvalueoftextarea={setsecondvalueoftextarea}
        />
      </div>
    )
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's my `ResultPanel.js`

```
import React from "react";

function ResultPanel(props) {
  const [firstvalueoftextarea, setfirstvalueoftextarea] = React.useState(
    "Hello World"
  );
  const [secondvalueoftextarea, setsecondvalueoftextarea] = React.useState("");

  props.PanelOfResult(
    firstvalueoftextarea,
    setfirstvalueoftextarea,
    secondvalueoftextarea,
    setsecondvalueoftextarea
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{firstvalueoftextarea}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ResultPanel;
```

The states of the ResultPanel Component can be changed by SecondChildComponent and ThirdChildComponent and those component code is working fine.

When SecondChildComponent tries to change the state of ResultPanel I'm getting the error- **TypeError: this.props.setvalueoftextarea is not a function**

Can anyone help where I'm mistaking? I'm not certain where to call PanelOfResult callback method in ResultPanel component.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of issues here, one of the biggest being how you set your variables for state.

First, move your state declarations to the parent component, and delete your vars. The whole `PanelOfResult` is unnecessary and a bad pattern of doing things.

```js
function App() {
  const [firstvalueoftextarea, setfirstvalueoftextarea] = React.useState(
    "Hello World"
  );
  const [secondvalueoftextarea, setsecondvalueoftextarea] = React.useState("");
```

Then, instead of passing the callback, pass the needed values:

```js
<ResultPanel firstvalueoftextarea={firstvalueoftextarea} />
```

This will stop your error about not being a function, and eliminate the need for a callback.

In general you should try not to use `var`, but `let` or `const`.

Also, try naming variables better. Either camel case or underscore would make your code much more readable.

Comment: Well, thanks for your response. But first thing is that my initial code was exactly same and worked perfectly. The reason I moved the ResulPanel as a separate Comp. is that upon changing the state the entire App is re rendering itself which will ultimately re render the second and third Comp. unnecessarily which I don't want. I prevent second & third component from re-rendering by returning false in componentShouldUpdate method. But what to do when the entire app component re-renders itself when I want only a piece of it to re-render(that's why made the separate Comp.)? Suggestions are welcome

Comment: I don't know how intensive the other two child components are, but unless they're doing a lot, the re-render seems negligible. But besides that, all three child components are using that state, so when it changes they need to re-render, regardless of where the state is held, because their props will have changed.